# Is the map $f(a+bi)=a$ a homomorphism of rings?

Tags: ring-theory

Is the map $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb Z$, $f(a+bi)=a$, for $a,b$ in $\mathbb Z$, a homomorphism of rings?

Any one could give me some ideas please?

Comment: It seems like the domain of this function is really the gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and not all of $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 3):

No.

If it was a homomorphism, then $f[(a+bi)(c+di)]=f(a+bi)f(c+di)=ac$

But $f[(a+bi)(c+di)]=f[(ac-bd) + (ad+bc)i]=ac-bd$

Comment: If it were homework, then perhaps a better answer would be $f(i)^2 = 0^2 = 0 \ne -1 = f(-1) = f(i^2)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, really helpful i understand the homomorphism of rings now.

Answer (score 2):

Verify the properties of a ring homomorphism $f$:

$f((a + ib)(c + id)) = f(ac + i(ad + bc) - bd) = ac - bd \neq f(a + ib)f(c + id) = ac$.

So the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

With even less computation: Since $i^2=-1$ the set $\{a+bi | a=0\}$ is not an ideal in $\mathbb Z[i]$